# Override Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, sleep, thread-sleep

We have few classes which extends a base class. We noticed that we use quit a few sleeps method and we wanted to log when a sleep occurs. Is there a way to override the Thread.sleep method in which I can add some custom logic ( ie logging) and then just call the actual Thread.sleep()? This way I wouldn't have to change all the places where Thread.sleep is being used in my bases classes. I'm open to other options as well.

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is a static method, and so you cannot override it.

Comment: Would there be a better alternative to achieve what I need ie being able to log when a sleep occurs without having to change all my code?

Comment: Call your own method which do `Thread.sleep()` and the logging. There is no reason to override it.

Comment: Not really. You could always write a custom static sleep method, but that would require you to replace all `Thread.sleep()` calls with it.

Comment: Short answer, no. Long answer, maybe with AOP? You might also have to use a custom class loader and byte code manipulation on `java.lang.Thread`.

Comment: you could call Thread.sleep() in your custom method and print a log. Or like @ElliottFrisch mentions, AOP could be used..

Comment: Yeah I was trying to avoid having to refactor all the code to call this new custom method by overriding it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot override `Thread.sleep` method, you cannot instrument or transform it either as it's a native method. One way is to automatically add logging to all places which call Thread.sleep using a Java Agent.

While the following approach works and is quite fun, in your case it's probably much better to refactor all calls to the `Thread.sleep` into a separate method and add the logging there.

You can find an [introduction to Java Agents here](http://www.javabeat.net/introduction-to-java-agents/). In a nutshell it's a special mechanism which allows (among other) transformation of loaded Java byte code. The following example of an Java Agent class automatically enhances all calls to the Thread.sleep with System.out logging and measure time spent in the method:

```
package fi.schafer.agent;

import javassist.CannotCompileException;
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtMethod;
import javassist.expr.ExprEditor;
import javassist.expr.MethodCall;

import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

public class LoggingAgent {

    public static void premain(String agentArgument, Instrumentation instrumentation) throws Exception {
        instrumentation.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {
            @Override
            public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
                return doClass(className, classBeingRedefined, classfileBuffer);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Method enhances calls to Thread.sleep with logging.
     */
    private static byte[] doClass(String name, Class clazz, byte[] b) {
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        CtClass cl = null;
        try {
            cl = pool.makeClass(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(b));
            final CtMethod[] targetMethods = cl.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (CtMethod targetMethod : targetMethods) {
                targetMethod.instrument(new ExprEditor() {
                    public void edit(final MethodCall m) throws CannotCompileException {
                        if ("java.lang.Thread".equals(m.getClassName()) && "sleep".equals(m.getMethodName())) {
                            m.replace("{long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis(); " +
                                    "$_ = $proceed($$); " +
                                    "long endMs = System.currentTimeMillis();" +
                                    "System.out.println(\"Logging Thread.sleep call execution, ms: \" + (endMs-startMs));}");
                        }
                    }
                });
                return cl.toBytecode();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Could not instrument  " + name
                    + ",  exception : " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (cl != null) {
                cl.detach();
            }
        }
        return b;
    }

}
```

You will need to compile it into a loggerAgent.jar file and include the following META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in it:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: fi.schafer.agent.LoggingAgent
Boot-Class-Path: javassist.jar
```

[Download JavaAssist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) and put it into same folder as your jar with compiled Agent. Run your application with parameter `-javaagent:loggerAgent.jar`.

You can [download a full example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3rIGUI8qqgMVkZiWEtteHE5UlU/edit?usp=sharing). Just extract it, open folder release and run the application with `java -cp loggerAgent.jar -javaagent:loggerAgent.jar Test`

More information and more examples can be found in this [excellent article](https://today.java.net/article/2008/04/22/add-logging-class-load-time-java-instrumentation).