# Why we need to use Thread.sleep() instead Sleep() in Java?

Tags: java, thread-sleep

Why we have to use `Thread.sleep()` instead of just `sleep()` in Java? What are reason, that forces developers to use "longer" version?

Comment: Explicitly letting readers of the code know where the method is coming from. You can use static import to ise just sleep()

Comment: Because `sleep` is a static method of `Thread`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `sleep()` is a **static method** of `Thread`. You could import it static, and then use `sleep()`

```
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try
        {
            sleep( 1000 );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

see here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

see also here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/421127/461499) on why to use static imports sparelingly.

Comment: If the Thread class is extended .. even we can use this.sleep() right ?

Comment: You can, but shouldn't. What if you override sleep()? Use Thread.sleep() or MyExtendedThread.sleep().

Comment: Yeagh and if it's extended and overriden then static import of sleep method won't work right?. so after all using the Thread.sleep() seems better.

Comment: I tried and checked. You cannot really override `sleep()` as it is a native method. You can create a static method `sleep()` in a subclass. But it will never be called somehow.. Weird.

Comment: See this answer for a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24448585/461499

Comment: I just wanted to say, It's always better to call the Thread.sleep() method than importing the static method and calling just sleep() method.

Comment: @RobAu You can override native methods. You cannot override static methods but you can shadow them: `MyThread.sleep(1000)`

Comment: @xehpuk, I tried that; `public static void sleep()` in `MyThread`  but the result is that `Thread.sleep()` is still called when `MyThread.sleep()` in the code.

Comment: You are correct, I tried it again and saw I had a mistake in the method signature... Then it will never be called :o

Answer (score 0):

Java is an object oriented language - every method ("function") must belong to a class, even if it's a `static` method (consider, e.g., that there's no "global" `print` function - you must call `System.out.print`). If it really annoys you, though, you could statically import the method:

```
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep

public class MyClass {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        sleep (10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sleep()` method in `Thread` class is a `static` method. We don't access `static` methods using the instance object.

Both the `this.sleep()` and `Thread.sleep()` are the same but it's against the conventions.

`static` keyword means it's common to all the classes there for if you use an *instance* variable to access a `static` method it's not clear.