# How to override Sleep to disable it

Tags: vb.net, overriding, sleep

Is it possible to ovverride VB .NET's System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() so it would be disabled?

It would be simple to do it from a common file instead of commenting that line a few times in hundreds of files I have.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444821/override-thread-sleep same question for Java, but as far as I know the method works the same in .net

Comment: have you tried anything for this?